# EmberJS: Allow Optional ID in Resource

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Using Emberjs, I would like to follow the REST specification, whereby an array of all objects is returned when no `id` is specified:

- `http://localhost:4200/database` returns all databases (would be `databases`)
- `http://localhost:4200/database/:id` returns the database info for a provided database (as expected)

My routes are defined as follows:

```
Router.map ->
    @resource "database", ":database_id", ->
        @route "new"
        @route "edit"
```

How can I allow for an optional `id` in my resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not the biggest fan of CoffeeScript so ill be replying with good old JavaScript.

So your routes look wrong, they should be as follows

```
App.Router.map(function() {
   this.resource("databases", function() {
       this.route("new"),
       this.resource("databases", { path: '/databases/:id' }, function() {
          this.route("edit"),
       });
   });
});
```

this would give you the following,

```
/databases (list of databases )
/databases/new  ( create a new database )
/databases/:id  ( view a database with id :id)
/databases/:id/edit  (edit the database with id of :id )
```

this removes the need for needing an optional ID.

Comment: Using those routes, Ember will still make requests to ``/databases``, even though I explicitly call my route ``database``.  Perhaps it has to do with this?  http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/Ember.Inflector.html  Ideas?